# Vb script to db echo results

Tags: sql, vbscript, plesk

I have this script on my hosting server, and the scheduler from plesk returns the results to the server, as this is just excecuting, how to i echo the results so plesk sends me the output?

```
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=server;Initial 
Catalog=db;user id ='user';password='password'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
myCommand.CommandText = "select COUNT (*)  FROM [Table].[dbo].[User]"
myCommand.Execute
```

myConn.Close

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
...
myCommand.CommandText = "select COUNT (*) AS CNT FROM [Table].[dbo].[User]"
myCommand.Execute

Do Until myCommand.Eof = True
    WScript.echo myCommand("CNT")
    myCommand.MoveNext
Loop

myConn.Close
```

I referred the page below (Japanese):

http://www.happy2-island.com/vbs/cafe02/capter00604.shtml